# Discovering single or specific iscsi targets

Tags: iscsi, discovery

I am using `iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p 10.1.1.100` to discover new targets and then `iscsiadm --mode node --targetname iqn... --portal 10.1.1.100:3260 --op=delete` to delete any targets I do not need.

Can I run discovery for specific target names and not having to delete all other unwanted targets ?

There is a similar question here but I am not sure it is what I need to do 
([Log in to a single LUN of a target with iscsiadm (open-iscsi)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/718304/log-in-to-a-single-lun-of-a-target-with-iscsiadm-open-iscsi))

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, it can be done by setting the static list of targets, something like this:

```
iscsiadm add static-config \ iqn.1999-08.com.array:sn.01234567,10.0.0.1:3260
```

Maybe this link will be helpful https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=iscsiadm&category=1

Comment: Thank you, I will try it the next time I will reboot my physical box and see If it solves my problem.